# WPF: How to play a video

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, video, mediaelement

I tried using the standard MediaElement control to play a file, but I cannot get it to appear at all nor to play on Windows 8.1. I tried converting my file to various formats. It started as an MP4 file from the Mac, then I converted it using ffmpeg to WMV and then to MPG. None of these files would play. I am willing to convert it to an animated GIF, if there were a sure fire way to get that to play. Any help is appreciated. I am using the sample XAML code that is provided by Microsoft, and I have tried some XAML examples from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Mp4 format is supported and it should work. Try some other video. Are you using the mediaelement class?

try this one with your videofile name

OR

Also debug to check if above events are fired.

If still it does not work please read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986967.aspx) in detail and see what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had the same problem as me, but I got .mpg files and .wmv to work after some confusing problems.

```
<MediaElement Grid.Row="0" Source="VideoElements\Wildlife.wmv" Name="myMediaElement" 
Width="450" Height="250" Opacity="1" Volume="1" LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Stretch="Fill" />

<Image Source="images\ui_play.gif" MouseDown="OnMouseDownPlayMedia" Margin="5" />


void OnMouseDownPlayMedia(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
  // The Play method will begin the media if it is not currently active or  
  // resume media if it is paused. This has no effect if the media is 
  // already running.
  myMediaElement.Play();
}
```

You can try this code, and see if you can get it to work. If not i'll check if I did something else :P But remember to set your Files Build Action to "Embedded Resource" in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say without seeing any of your code. A few months back I got video working from this tutorial: [Playing video](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/playing-video/).

Here's the most basic snippet from it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Audio_and_Video.MediaPlayerVideoSizeSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MediaPlayerVideoSizeSample" Height="500" Width="500" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Source="http://hubblesource.stsci.edu/sources/video/clips/details/images/hst_1.mpg" Name="mePlayer" Stretch="None" />
</Grid>
```

I was using full paths to files on disk in MediaElement.Source (ex: C:\Videos\SomeVideo.mp4) and it worked fine with a handful of extensions, including .mp4 and .wmv.

If that doesn't work for you, try looking in the output window in Visual Studio while debugging. You might see some exception or message in it that is telling of why things aren't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Mediaelment in your XAML:

```
<MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Manual" Name="MediaPlayer" Height="200" Visibility="Visible"
                              Source="{Binding VidoPath}" />
```

Thanks